# How to insert the values in two different table when using if and else with it

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert the values in two different tables based on the if and else condition. But i am getting error of else statement when used second time. All the page goes blank if i use else{?> before html elements. Please help me out.

I have used if and else in many ways.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>GlobalWorkOnline Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require('db.php');
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if($_GET['viewregistrationid']!="") {

    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

        $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query = "INSERT into `freelancer_details` (username, password, fullname, trn_date) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$name', '$trn_date')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($result){
            echo "<div class='form text-center'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
    }
   }

   else { 

    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        # code...
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

        $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query = "INSERT into `employer_details` (username, password, fullname, trn_date) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$name', '$trn_date')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($result){
            echo "<div class='form text-center'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
}
}




 else {?>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center head">GlobalWorkOnline Registration Form</h1>
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 rform">
<form class="form-horizontal" name="registration" action="" method="post">

    <div class="form-group content">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Full Name :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group content">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="uname">Username :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group content">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-9">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
        <input class="buttonregister" type="submit" class="register" name="submit" value="Register" />
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The values should be inserted properly but the page goes blank.

Comment: Couple notes: 1) Look into "prepared statements" for your INSERT 2) md5 is very insecure for storing passwords, use php's password_hash() instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert value into two different tables by using id getting from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372813/how-to-insert-value-into-two-different-tables-by-using-id-getting-from-another-p)

Answer (score 1):

You have used a structure like: `if...else...else`
You have to specify a condition for the second else if u want to use the third one. For ex,
u can't write: `if($var==1) { ... } else { ... } else { ... }`, and u need to add an if:

```
if($var==1) { ... } else if($var==2) { ... } else { ... }
```